# Simply-connected compact Lie group v.s. semi-simple Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, compactness, connectedness, reductive-groups

> 1. If G is a simply-connected compact Lie group, is it true that its Lie algebra must be semi-simple?

What I found is that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_group#Classification: The classification of compact, simply connected Lie groups is the same as the classification of complex semisimple Lie algebras. Indeed, if K is a simply connected compact Lie group, then the **complexification** of the Lie algebra of K is semisimple. Conversely, every complex semisimple Lie algebra has a compact real form isomorphic to the Lie algebra of a compact, simply connected Lie group.

> 2. Does thie above text imply that "If G is a simply-connected compact Lie group, is it true that the **complexification** of its Lie algebra must be semi-simple?"

Comment: Yes, if the complexification of a real Lie algebra is semisimple, then the original Lie algebra must be semisimple.

Comment: hi, what is the difference between the wikipedia quotation and your sentence at point 2?